Why is Amazon Pay's modal window giving me the message "You can’t continue in this page. To continue, close this page"?
I am implementing Amazon Pay v2 on our checkout page. I'm using the sandbox right now with a sandbox test user. When I click on the amazon pay button, then a modal window pops up asking me to login. I login with my test user credentials and then it shows a message of:
You can’t continue in this page
To continue, close this page

Here's a screenshot of that message:

Here is my code for the button:
async initializeAmazonPayV2Button() {
  try {
    // Get checkout session details from the backend
    const { payloadJSON, signature } = await this.createCheckoutSession();

    console.log('this.apMerchantId', this.apMerchantId)
    console.log('this.apPublicKey', this.apPublicKey)
    console.log('payloadJSON', payloadJSON);
    console.log('signature', signature);

    // Initialize the Amazon Pay V2 button
    new amazon.Pay.renderButton('#AmazonPayV2Button', {
      // Set the environment
      merchantId: this.apMerchantId,
      publicKeyId: this.apPublicKey,
      ledgerCurrency: 'USD',

      // Customize the buyer experience
      checkoutLanguage: 'en_US',
      productType: 'PayAndShip',
      placement: 'Checkout',
      // estimatedOrderAmount: { 'amount': this.estTotal.toFixed(2), currencyCode: 'USD' },
      createCheckoutSessionConfig: {
        payloadJSON: payloadJSON,
        signature: signature,
        algorithm: 'AMZN-PAY-RSASSA-PSS-V2',
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.error('Amazon Pay V2 Error:', error);
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to initialize Amazon Pay V2 Button:', error);
  }
},

Here is the payload:
payload = {
    "storeId": settings.AMAZON_PAY_V2_STORE_ID,  # Replace with your Amazon Store ID
    "webCheckoutDetails": {
        "checkoutReviewReturnUrl": checkout_review_url,
    },
    "chargePermissionType": "OneTime",
    "scopes": ["name", "email", "phoneNumber", "billingAddress"]
}
payload_json = json.dumps(payload)

I don't think this is an issue with the signature because before this when the modal window would pop up (before it asked for a login) it would give me an error telling me the signature didn't match. I figured out my signature and now it just asks me to login.
I've also verified all the values of the variables that get inserted into the renderButton() and it looks exactly correct.
I've used the Amazon Pay ScratchPad and it works correctly. After logging in it redirects me back to my return URL with the checkout session ID added as a query parameter.
I've compared the values from the ScratchPad with what I'm using and the seem to be the exact same. Only difference is they're using one of their SDK's to create the signature whereas I'm using my own Python code to create the signature.
I'm just at a loss. I wish Amazon would give more info other than "You can’t continue in this page".
Has anyone ran into this issue before? Or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Can you share your createCheckoutSessionConfig.payloadJSON? And is it exactly the same as in their scratchpad? I'd suppose the error somewhere there as all the signature and key stuff produces "real" errors with other messages.

I did pay a lot of attention to the payloadJSON that scratchpad was passing, because it was different from mine. So I tried making it the same but it didn't do anything. Scratchpad tends to put in quite a few keys that are just blank or empty too. I updated my question with the payload I'm using.
